# send data from iOS app to externally connected non iOS device

Tags: ios, external-accessory

I am developing one iOS app . Concept is I have an iOS device and one batterycase (It is connected to iOS device using connector. These batterycases are made my our company). If I click on button in iOS app, it should switch on the batterycase switch and starts charging the iPhone.

1 . Can anyone please tell me how to communicate with batterycase using iOS app through the connector .

2 . Does this batterycase need to subscribe the apple MFi program ?

Any suggestions or links would be very helpful .
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you want your iOS app to communicate to your accessory, it is mandatory you use the mFi chip and you must request apple for that. Without that you can not talk to external accessory. And there is a separate framework called "External Accessory", provided by Apple, for this purpose. Good Luck!